# Binding inner ContentControl control to parent ItemsControl item

Tags: wpf, binding, itemscontrol, contentcontrol

I think I almost got it but struggling with final solution.

- I have *BoardList* `ItemsControl` that has N number of items - all
  works.
- I have an inner *Eeprom* `ContentControl` that contains certain fields - everything works except I have to bind button's `Tag` to `ItemsControl` item.  In code behind I will cast this `Tag` to *Board* object and do all kinds of stuff.

As you can see, I tried using `RelativeSource` but it's taking me to an actual `ItemsControl`, not an item itself.  It's probably something stupid I'm missing but I just can't get it.
Any help appreciated.  Thanks!

```
<!--List of "Board" items-->
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding BoardList}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <GroupBox>
                <!--Eeprom is an object within "Board" item-->
                <ContentControl Content="{Binding Eeprom}">
                    <ContentControl.ContentTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <StackPanel>
                                <TextBox Text="{Binding IdPage}"/>
                                <Button Tag="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ItemsControl}}" Click="Button_Click"/>
                            </StackPanel>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ContentControl.ContentTemplate>
                </ContentControl>
            </GroupBox>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

Complete version (I unintentionally left of important containers):

```
<!--List of "Board" items-->
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding ContrSysAccessor.IBoardList}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <!--Eeprom is an object within "Board" item-->
            <ContentControl Content="{Binding Eeprom}">
                <ContentControl.ContentTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <materialDesign:ColorZone>
                            <materialDesign:PopupBox>
                                <StackPanel>
                                    <TextBox Text="{Binding IdPage}"/>
                                    <Button Tag="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ContentControl}, Path=DataContext}" Click="Button_Click"/>
                                </StackPanel>
                            </materialDesign:PopupBox>
                        </materialDesign:ColorZone>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ContentControl.ContentTemplate>
            </ContentControl>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple controls derived from `ContentControl` in the control hierarchy:

- `ContentControl` (yours)

  - `materialDesign:ColorZone`

    - `materialDesign:PopupBox`

      - `materialDesign:Card` (not shown)

That is why your binding does not work. It will return the data context of the *first* control while traversing the parent controls. This control is `materialDesign:Card` and its data context `Eeprom`.

You can make your binding work, if you specify which `ContentControl` in the hierarchy you want. This is defined by the `AncestorLevel`. Your target `ContentControl` is the *fourth* in the parent hierarchy, so specify `4`.

```
<Button Tag="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ContentControl, AncestorLevel=4}, Path=DataContext}" Click="Button_Click"/>
```

---

An alternative to a `RelativeSource` binding, that works here, is setting an `x:Name` on your target `ContentControl` and referring to it in the binding with `ElementName`.

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Parent}">
   <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
      <DataTemplate>
         <!--Eeprom is an object within "Board" item-->
         <ContentControl x:Name="MyContentControl" Content="{Binding Text}">
            <ContentControl.ContentTemplate>
               <DataTemplate>
                  <materialDesign:ColorZone>
                     <materialDesign:PopupBox>
                        <StackPanel>
                           <TextBox Text="{Binding Mode=OneWay}"/>
                           <Button Tag="{Binding DataContext, ElementName=MyContentControl}" Click="Button_Click"/>
                        </StackPanel>
                     </materialDesign:PopupBox>
                  </materialDesign:ColorZone>
               </DataTemplate>
            </ContentControl.ContentTemplate>
         </ContentControl>
      </DataTemplate>
   </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

Comment: THANK you!  It helps that you know this MD library because I forgot that PopupBox is built with a Card.  In any case, very helpful mini tutorial.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You might want to try getting the `DataContext` of the `ContentControl` instead.

```
<Button Tag="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ContentControl}, Path=DataContext}" Click="Button_Click"/>
```

Comment: Keithernet, thank you! Your answer worked (after I adjusted my structure to what I actually originally posted). I simplified it here thinking it'd make it cleaner and missed out containers that make a diff. I just edited the original post with complete structure, which still doesn't work.  As you can see, there are 2 inner custom `ContentControl`s and I know this is what screws me up because if I remove them, your solution works.  Could you please let me know how to get around this?  Thank you.  I know there is a `FindAncestor` mode but I can't make it work.